# Динамическое установление типа в зависимости от условия

Tags: c#, типы-данных

Есть две сборки (`service reference`) в одном `namespace OrderSendService`. Обе имеют класс `Order`:

```
public class Order
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }
}
```

`ServiceReference1` и `ServiceReference2`, это Service references, полученные на основе wsdl. Мне нужно использовать оба этих референса. Сейчас  формируется объект  `ServiceReference1.Order` и отправляется методом `ServiceReference1.Send()`. Возникла необходимость для отправки использовать `ServiceReference2.Send()` и передавать этот же объект (при этом ServiceReference2.Send() принимает объекты из своего `namespace`)

Возможно ли в зависимости от условия, установить тип объекту? Использую такой код:

```
dynamic obj;
if (condition)
{
   obj = new ServiceReference1.Order[10];
}
else
{
   obj = new ServiceReference2.Order[10];
}
```

(`obj` будет передаваться в методе `Send()` одного из wsdl-сервисов).

Неймспейсы сервисов:

```
OrderSendService.ServiceReference1
OrderSendService.ServiceReference2
```

При попытке доступа к свойству `obj[0].id` `VS 2015` показывает ошибку:

> Missing compiler required member
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create

И возможно ли привести тип `ServiceReference1.Order` к `ServiceReference2.Order`?

Comment: Зачем вам две абсолютно одинаковые сущности?

Comment: А они в одном пространстве имён или нет? Если в разных, чем ваш код из вопроса не подходит?

Comment: @AGS17, это два разных класса на основе wsdl с разных урлов. Их методы принимают объекты только своей сборки

Comment: @VladD, это два сервис референс в общем пространстве имен win сервиса. Если попытаться получить значение `obj[0].id` проект не собирается

Comment: @Sv__t: Хм, общий namespace? А какой хотя бы?

Comment: "проект не собирается" - а что делает?

Comment: @VladD, обновил вопрос

Comment: @Sv__t: А как компилируется `Assembly1`? Что это такое?

Comment: Окей, так уже лучше. А у вас в References есть ссылка на `Microsoft.CSharp`?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать один и тот же объект и там и там?

Comment: @VladD, подключил, не поменялось ничего

Comment: @Sv__t: Ага, то есть подключено не было. А вы подключали правильную версию?

Comment: @VladD, разобрался, спасибо! Да, подключал нужную мне 4.0 версию, но почему-то VS не видела ссылку что ли. Перезагрузка вроде помогла

Comment: @Sv__t: То есть с `Microsoft.CSharp` теперь работает?

Comment: А контракты служб у вас - полностью одинаковые или там только Order совпадает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, не хватало подключения библиотеки `Microsoft.CSharp`. Поскольку `dynamic` — внутри-C#-овская фича, ей нужна специальная поддержка.

Проекты, созданные старыми версиями компилятора, не содержат ссылки на `Microsoft.CSharp`, поэтому ссылку иногда приходится добавлять вручную.

Comment: Плюс в моем случае еще потребовалось перезагружать студию

Answer (score 2):

Заведите для разных служб разные пространства имен. Вы искуственно создаете ситуацию, когда .NET не имеет возможности различить два типа `Order` в том месте кода, где они "видны".

> И возможно ли привести тип `ServiceReference1.Order` к
>   `ServiceReference2.Order`

Нет.

```
public class OrderConverter
{
  public static ServiceReference1.Order Convert(ServiceReference2.Order anOrder)
  {
    return new ServiceReference1.Order()
    {
      id = anOrder.id;
      type = anOrder.type;
    };
  }

  public static ServiceReference2.Order Convert(ServiceReference1.Order anOrder)
  {
    return new ServiceReference2.Order()
    {
      id = anOrder.id;
      type = anOrder.type;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: сейчас пространства имен: `OrderSendService.ServiceReference1` и `OrderSendService.ServiceReference2`. Вы это имеете ввиду?